# How to get position of any touch and to process on it?(android)

Tags: android, delphi-xe5

For example,i have form with 2 buttons.
I click on button1,and after click on button2 with another finger.How to create event for button2 and get second touch coordinate?

Answer (score 0):

If you touch button 2 while keeping button 1 pressed, button 2 will not get any event.

Check http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnTouchListener.html
You should attach onTouchListener to button 1, and for each ACTION_POINTER_DOWN in the motion event, check that the x and y coordinates are inside button 2 bounds.

Comment: How to do this in Rad Studio XE5?There are no such functions:(

Answer (score 0):

It may be useful to query the Android developer website to see the implementation of the touch method http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnTouchListener.html

The setOnTouchListener is similar to the setOnClickListener in the way it is used.Here is a code example:

```
imageButton.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){

            // Do what you want
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```